# Can't access k8s service from another pod- Connection Timeout

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two pods running, each in separate namespaces- call them A and B.

I send a request from pod A to pod B. Yet, the connection is refused. I have verified that DNS is working and it indeed resolves to the ip address of service B.

Yet, when I send the request, it is always refused. To further verify this, I ran a busybox container in namespace A and tried to run the following, as described by the [debug service document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/debug-service/#running-commands-in-a-pod).

```
for ep in <ENDPOINT_IP:PORT>; do
    wget -qO- $ep
done
```

However, even this results in `Connection refused`.

If I port-forward the service, I can access the pod without an issue- it's only when I try to access via a request from another pod.

The cluster is a public cluster deployed on GKE Autopilot.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect by changing the port from 8080 to 8081- not sure why this made a difference.

However, I still get occasional timeouts i.e. it's not instant connection. If anybody knows possible reasons why this happens, please share!

Comment: Can you share the Deployment and Service definition of your pods and services please ?